# Thumbnail from a live stream (video file .m3u8)

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I get a `snapshot from a live stream` (video file .m3u8) to use it as a thumbnail?

- I have already tried **Glide** but it does not work.

Do you have any idea if there is any library that can do such?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by fetching the thumbnail from the server.